# A word meaning a choice made for self advantage

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for a choice that is made by someone to his advantage, but somewhat against his principles. Begins with 'co' I think. Not 'pragmatic'. More a suggestion  of manipulation, deviousness, slightly cynical, compromising for gain.

Comment: I doubt it's the word you seek (thus a comment and not an answer), but just in case: **co**rrupt? Or **co**nniving?

Comment: To _make an accommodation_ can carry the connotation of compromise.

Answer (score 1):

> **self-serving** *- serving to further one's own selfish interests* [<sub><sup>(http://dictionary.reference.com/)</sup></sub>](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-serving)

A common alternative is **self-seeking**. Related terms include **bias** and **vested interest**.

Comment: Also **self-oriented**.

Answer (score 0):

#### Machiavellian

> characterized by subtle or unscrupulous cunning, deception,
>   expediency, or dishonesty ~ [*Dictionary.com*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/machiavellian)
>
> using clever lies and tricks in order to get or achieve something :
>   clever and dishonest ~ [Merriam-Website.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/machiavellian)

*Among the job applicants, most highlighted their record of achievement, allowing their past work to speak for itself. One guy, however, took a different route, complimenting my attire, sharing his "secrets" about the other applicants, and resorting to other Machiavellian tactics.*

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't begin with "co", but "expedient" fits your description.

expedient
ɪkˈspiːdɪənt,ɛk-
adjective
1.
(of an action) convenient and practical although possibly improper or immoral.
synonyms:   convenient, advantageous, in one's own interests, to one's own advantage, useful, of use, of service, beneficial, of benefit, profitable, gainful, effective, helpful

Your "that" and "which" are the right way around (unless I'm sadly mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't precisely fit your question description, but I think ***co-opt*** was the word you were trying to remember:

> : to cause or force (someone or something) to become part of your group, movement, etc.
>   : to use or take control of (something) for your own purposes
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/co-opt)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ideas:

**[sell-out](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sellout?showCookiePolicy=true)** behaviour which used to be against someone's principles, or which gives in to an opposing group   ⇒ "For some, his decision to become a Socialist candidate at Sunday's election was simply a sell-out."

**cop-out** I can't quote or link to anything.  I'm not finding any online dictionary defining this the way I have in mind.  I'll give you a definition of the sense that I am familiar with, though: When you take the easy way out, you can say that you're copping out.  For example: *After six months of being unemployed, his principles and qualms didn't matter any more.  He copped out and took a job at the coal mine.*